# Disabling music on gba Final Fantasy Tactics Advance

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance, final-fantasy-tactics-advance

Is there any way to disable music?

There is no game option. I already tried playing the rom on emulators but could not find any way to disable only the music and leave sounds playing. Is there any emulator that allows this, something like disabling some audio channel?

Comment: have you tried VisualBoyAdvance? under Options > Sound there is an Off option

Comment: bruh the music in that game is great!

Comment: @GarrettJ taste is taste :) I hate that music more than having to press A for 1 hour  for the unskippable intro every time I try to pick this game... sigh why do I even bother with it haha. anyway the music sounds like a 80s wacky movie sound track. awfull :)

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to adjust sound balance in-game (reducing the volume of music without simply reducing the volume of all sounds).

I have found no mention of it in a [comprehensive walkthrough](http://ca.ign.com/faqs/2006/final-fantasy-tactics-advance-walkthrough-455274), or in the [manual](https://cdn02.nintendo-europe.com/media/downloads/games_8/emanuals/game_boy_advance_8/Manual_GameBoyAdvance_FinalFantasyTacticsAdvance_EN_DE_FR_ES_IT.pdf).

As additional evidence, tried searching through various menus.

It's not on the title screen...
[image]

World Menu...
[image]

System menu...
[image]

or Options menu
[image]

Comment: wow great detail. but I had mentioned that there was no in game option. I was hopping for an emulator option or even a game secret code, anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Visualboy Advance Emulator and disabling the Sound Channels in "Tools > Sound Channels >"

Disable these two options:
Direct Sound A
Direct Sound B

I tried this for "Kirby - Nightmare in Dreamland" and it seems to work. It disables only the Background Music and other sounds work.